Manhua where the male lead is cursed by a blue dragon and the female lead must work out how to save him
The female lead, who transmigrates into the story, discovers that the male lead is cursed by a blue dragon and destined to die in six months. The curse causes him to turn anything or anyone he touches into ice, which is why he always wears gloves. Despite looking healthy, no one believes him about the curse except for the female lead.
She has the power to restore things to their past state and attempts to break the curse by reviving a frozen rose, which is the key to lifting it. However, the male lead is initially suspicious of her and thinks she might be a spy sent by the emperor.
I recall that the female lead in the original novel is abused by her family and the male lead in the original novel is just a side character.

Likely a dupe of Manhwa/manhua where the female lead marries the male lead who has a curse that freezes people he touches - I Don't Want the Obsession of a Twisted Archduke...? In the original plot of the novel, Ridel was forced to marry the Archduke of the North, Kyle Romani, who was afflicted with a 'Curse of Ice' by a blue dragon he killed. The curse caused his human emotions to be replaced by those of the dragon, froze anyone he touched, and killed him six months after marrying Ridel. -

Is this I Don't Want the Obsession of a Twisted Archduke...?

I reincarnated as the wife of a cursed archduke in my own twisted novel. As the author, I took responsibility and set things right by lifting the curse, which was the key to returning home. I thought my job was done, and just when I was finally trying to go back, the archduke asked me, "Did you really think I wouldn't know that you’re planning on returning to your fiance?" He had completely misunderstood! "Whether you like it or not, I'm still your husband. I'm never letting you go back to that bastard." All I want is for him to please let me go home!


In this Korean manhwa, an office worker is hit by a truck and wakes up in the world of a novel she'd written as Ridel Spencer, the illegitimate and abused daughter of a noble.
In the original plot of the novel, Ridel was forced to marry the Archduke of the North, Kyle Romani, who was afflicted with a 'Curse of Ice' by a blue dragon he killed. The curse caused his human emotions to be replaced by those of the dragon, froze anyone he touched, and killed him six months after marrying Ridel. She was then falsely accused of helping the main characters of the novel and executed.
This time, she decides to try and save both herself and Kyle by lifting his curse, hoping that this will allow her to return to the real world. Since she wrote the novel, she knows that Kyle is dying, whereas no one else believes that. She also knows that the key to breaking his curse is a flower he keeps hidden on the fifth floor of his mansion. Furthermore, she knows that Ridel has the power to reverse time on a small scale, enabling her to bring a trampled flower back to life.
